# How do I create a function that returns a list of integers from n to 1?

Tags: python

How do I write a function called `countdown` that counts down starting from `n` and goes until 1 ? The function should return a `list`, the contents of which should be integers going from `n` down to 1.

```
def countdown(n):
    if n >= 1:
        countdown(n-1)
    print(n)
```

Comment: So you want the countdown to be descending , am i right/

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack exchange. Let me save you some trouble, learn from my mistakes. 1.) Make your titles explicit. "What am I missing" doesn't tell us anything on its own. Try "How to write a countdown function?" 2.) Tell people what you've already tried and what the result was so you don't get accused of asking other people to write your code for you. What happens when you run this code here? 3.) See my formatting changes to learn how to make your questions more readable.

Comment: move the line `print(n)` inside the `if` before `countdown(n-1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to return a `list`, you need to create that list in the function.

```
def countdown(n):
    return list(range(n, 0, -1))
```

[`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) creates your sequence from n to 0 (non-inclusive, which means it'll stop at 1), with a step of -1 each time.

[`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) then converts the sequence into the list that you want returned.

This also means that you don't actually have to create a specific function for a countdown list. You can just directly call `list(range(n, 0, -1))`.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion:

```
def countdown(n):
    if n < 1:
        return []
    return [n] + countdown(n-1)
```

This approach provides the "base case" and creation of a list of integers once the base is reached.

Check out [this link](http://www.pythontutor.com/live.html#code=def%20countdown%28n%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20n%20%3C%201%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5Bn%5D%20%2B%20countdown%28n-1%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%20countdown%285%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=26&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-live.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) to visualize the execution. Do let me know if you have any questions.